# Line equation from ray form

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given a ray `r = u + (v)t` where `u` is a bounded vector representing an origin point and `v` is a free vector representing direction, how can the equation for the line in the form `y = mx + b` be derived?

Given:

$$u = \langle 0, \frac{-3}{4} \rangle$$
$$v = \langle 1, \frac{8}{9} \rangle$$

How does one arrive at:

$$y = \frac{8}{9}x + \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: 1. This is not appropriate for the algebraic geometry tag. 2. Please use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a vector $v$ that starts from point $u$. It means that the line is going to be parallel to $v$. We know that any vector ($a$) parallel to $v$ will have cross product $a \times v= 0$. But $a$ needs to be shifted by $u$ meaning:

$$
a=\langle x - 0, y + \frac{3}{4}\rangle
$$

Now cross product (a.k.a. $2\times2$ matrix determinant) would be:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x && 1 \\
y + \frac{3}{4} && \frac{8}{9}
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{8}{9}x - (y + \frac{3}{4}) = 0
$$
$$
y = \frac{8}{9}x - \frac{3}{4} 
$$
The sign in your answer was wrong, you can check that if you set $x=0$ , then the expression should give $- \frac{3}{4}$ since $u=\langle 0, - \frac{3}{4}\rangle$